# Special Comments in DELPHI

Tags: delphi, comments

I am looking to add special comments in Delphi Source Code. This is along the lines of "TODO" comments and the IDE (XE4) has a "Task List" option which lists all "TODO's".

Are there any plugins available where I can add some special comment tags for other purposes. For e.g if I want to mention and measure complex piece of code, I should comment the portion with my TAG and then using the plugin I can gather some statistics (simple count)

Thanks
Madhusudan

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. This is clearly stated in the guidelines in the [help], specifically in "What topics can I ask about here?" located [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You might try the [Embarcadero Delphi forums](https://forums.embarcadero.com/category.jspa?categoryID=12), specifically the [Delphi Third-Party Tools forum](https://forums.embarcadero.com/forum.jspa?forumID=92). Good luck.

Comment: there are a bunch of Delphi preprocessors like http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/dipp/index and http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JEDI_Pre_Processor Google and maybe you would find one for your needs

Comment: also http://sourceforge.net/p/dpp32/wiki/Home/

Comment: Can't you write your own template?